# How to define generic method that get T that contain some attribute ?

Tags: c#

I have some attribute that i define. 
I want to write some generic method that will get  where this  contain this attribute.

How to implement this ?

Comment: This attribute is for classes? You want to seek in your code where this attribute is being used?, give more information plz.

Comment: I dont think this is duplicate. OP wants to know how to check if type contains particular attribute in generic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with 'attribute' you mean property: That will only work if `T` is an interface or (base) class / struct. If not, it wouldn't work. You can't check for having a property or field, just if it implements or derives from.

If you don't have a shared interface or base class, your only option is to use `dynamic` or reflection.

If you mean 'attribute' as in attribute: not possible.